# What's wrong with delegation-based typeclasses encoding

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass

Typeclasses coherence is a well-known problem.

For example a `Monad` has to be a `Functor` and a `Traversable` has to be a `Functor` as well. If `has to be` is represented via inheritance (`Monad[F[_]] extends Functor[F[_]]`) then there will most probably be ambiguity in implicit resolution.

I applied the rule of thumb: if you have a problem with inheritance replace it by delegation. Here is an example:

```
  trait Semigroup[A] {
    def append(a: A, b: A): A
  }

  trait Monoid[A] {
    def zero(): A
    val semigroup: Semigroup[A]
    def append(a: A, b: A): A = semigroup.append(a, b)
  }

  implicit object IntSemigroup extends Semigroup[Int] {
    override def append(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
  }

  implicit object IntMonoid extends Monoid[Int] {
    override def zero(): Int = 0
    override val semigroup: Semigroup[Int] = IntSemigroup
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(implicitly[Monoid[Int]].append(2, 3))
  }
```

I guess this approach doesn't work since it's obvious but not used in scalaz/cats. Could you please point me to the problems?

Comment: *If has to be is represented via inheritance (Monad[F[_]] extends Functor[F[_]]) then there will most probably be ambiguity in implicit resolution.* Can you elaborate on what ambiguity you're referring to?

Comment: I mean if `ListTraversable` and `ListMonad` are both in scope they both match `Functor[List]` (In case of naive straightforward implementation).

Comment: I see. Since one subsumes the other, you'd still be ok by removing one from scope, but the issue is clear. There was a proposal for coherent typeclass annotation for Dotty which is suppose to handle this issue: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/2047

Answer (score 3):

With representing it using inheritance, you get inference for free - a `Monad` is automatically a `Functor`. With representing it using delegation, you don't.

You would have to define lots of implicit conversions to get around that, which would be a pain. But (simple) implicit conversions don't chain automatically in Scala, so with them, it still wouldn't infer `Functor` from `Monad` via the intermediate type class `Applicative`.

P.S. In practice, you usually don't get ambiguity in resolution if you do things right. That means, (a) use `foo.some` instead of `Some(foo)` and the like, and (b) use value classes or similar to semantically disambiguate types for which you wish to use different instances. And if all else fails, explicitly pass in the instance (which you can't do in Haskell).

Comment: Upcasts is a good point, thanks. But there should be bigger problems I guess. Maybe derivation?